# Share on Facebook / Twitter / E-mail feature using PhoneGap / jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm coding an app for iOS / WP7 / Android using PhoneGap and it has to allow the user to publish comments to its facebook wall / twitter or send it by e-mail.

What is the easy way to face these tasks? any common approach? maybe a plugin? I have seen some similar posts in stackoverflow but none of them seems to offer a plain solution for all platforms...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a nice one, it's a JQuery plugin that not only has a nice interface but also provides the implementation details (link) to actually share something on each one of those frameworks!

[jQuery social media share](http://www.egrappler.com/jquery-social-media-share-plugin-jsshare/)

If you want more access (like FB Wall), you'll need to actually code against the FB SDK (in javascript, not that hard but tons of functionality!).

PS: I am not affiliated in any way to this plugin or to it's author

Comment: Nice, but uses Google Buzz and not Google+. Buzz doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript based API's to make calls from your native apps that are not platform specific (so you can implement the same code in several native apps).

For instance, here is a link to the Facebook JavaScript API: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

For sending email, you could allow your users to compose the email in your app, then use an AJAX call to send the data to your server where your server-side script can send the email.

Answer (score 0):

here is a implemetation with javascript for facebook, email and twitter in a few lines of code: http://www.sebastianviereck.de/en/mobile-multi-share-implementation-with-jquery-mobile/