# javascript or php posting on facebook

Tags: facebook, post, share

in my application i am trying to post on user's wall on facebook. in some posts i've read you could use the facebook.com/share.php, but somehow i can't attach the text to the message to be posted on the wall.

there is a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808484/share-on-facebook-twitter-e-mail-feature-using-phonegap-jquerymobile) which includes a link to [here](http://www.sebastianviereck.de/en/mobile-multi-share-implementation-with-jquery-mobile/) but using the share.php solution doesn't seem to work.

how can i easily post on wall (given that user is already logged in or will be prompted to log in) using share.php? is there an easier way? is it even possible without registering and obtaining the API key?

Comment: post your code please and an error message if possible

Comment: i just use the link [link]("http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + encodeURIComponent(url) +"&status="+ encodeURIComponent(text)) . it adds the link to the post, but not the text. how can i post the text? how could i also append an image to the post?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a title="send to Facebook" 
href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=YOUR_TITLE&p[summary]=YOUR_SUMMARY&p[url]=YOUR_URL&p[images[0]=YOUR_IMAGE_TO_SHARE_OBJECT"
target="_blank">Share with Facebook</a>
```